# TYPO3 top 3 or 5 news from tx_news

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have search google for "top 3"/"top 5" and latest news, about the extension TX_News and i can't find any guides how to show a custom top 3 or 5 news, with typoscript inside a lib.

If u look at the bottom of [www.codem.dk](http://codem.dk) I want to show the latest 3 or 5 news in the middle of the footer "Seneste indlæg", but I can't find a tutorial showing or guide, how to do this.

Do someone have some info how to do this ?

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.1 with FLUID/EXTBASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set up a plugin on a hidden page/maybe a folder and set all the options in the FlexForm:
- limit to 3 news
- sort by given date descending
- maybe only show top news if you're using this feature

Then you just use the RECORD cObject to assign your plugin to a lib:

```
lib.latestNews = RECORDS
lib.latestNews.source = [content uid]
lib.latestNews.dontCheckPid = 1
lib.latestNews.tables = tt_content
```

Comment: Ok, as u can see i have fix it (see link) but it's using the list.html file that i have changes to my list view page.
How can I changes the layout, without edit the /templates/ext/news/Partials/List/Item.html file, can I somehow tell the news plugin on the hidden folder, to use another Item.html page like /templates/ext/news/Partials/List/top3item.html ?

Comment: I would go for having "Custom Layouts" for the same view, see documentation here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Templating/Additional/Index.html#custom-templates-by-using-the-layout-selector

Comment: thx i will try to use that, Can i add the tx_news.templateLayouts to the lib.latestNews so i there tell it to use template "top3" ?

Comment: RTFM :-). You configure the news plugin FlexForm to have a layout selector (using Page TS!). The layout you select in the FlexForm is passed to the variable {settings.templateLayout} in Fluid. Then you stay within your List/Item.html plugin but make a condition: <f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 1">Template for Layout 1</f:if><f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 2">Template for Layout 2</f:if>. So you still only have one template file, but it contains the template for both layouts.

Comment: Yes i got that, it was just about the TS handling. But thx ;-) and sry im a bit new to TYPO3 so need to know how its working and can see that the extensions is not working the same way.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean with "top 3" news? how do you get to this order? If this is a custom field in the tx_news_domain_model table, you can of course use this for the ordering and set a limit to 3 or 5.